# Zip code filter per seller - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I am implementing a web service in PHP that will retrieve a list of sellers who deliver at certain zip codes. I want to know any better approaches to do this than what I'm currently doing.

Sample table for zip codes (ziptable):

```
-----------------------
| seller_id | zipcode |
-----------------------
|    101    | 110012  |
-----------------------
|    101    | 110023  |
-----------------------
|    102    | 110023  |
-----------------------
```

Now I'm using the following query to get the list of sellers who deliver at zip code 110023:

```
SELECT * FROM sellers s, ziptable z
    WHERE z.zipcode = 110023 AND s.id = z.seller_id ;
```

Are there any better approaches to get the same result either by changing database schema or SQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to return any columns from the zipcodes table, but apart from that, with appropriate indexes, this is just fine. Note that we would normally write that more like this:

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM ziptable z
  JOIN sellers s
    ON z.seller_id = s.id
 WHERE z.zipcode = 110023;
```

Comment: Right. Thanks. And which fields should I index?

Comment: Well, you should already have a composite PRIMARY KEY on (z.seller_id,z.zipcode), as well as a PRIMARY KEY on s.seller_id, so there's really nothing left to index.

Comment: The explicit `join` syntax is much, much preferred over the less powerful comma-in-the-from clause approach.

Comment: @Strawberry - Wrong -- The PRIMARY KEY for `zipcode` needs to be reversed:  `(zipcode, seller_id)`.  This is because the optimizer will start with `ziptable` and search for the rows with `zipcode = 110023` (clearly not in the US, since it is six digits??).  Then it will `JOIN` to `sellers`.

Comment: @Shubham See RJ's comment above.